# fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found

Tags: perl, gtk

So I'm trying to install Gtk-Perl-0.7000 from http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk-Perl/ on a mac

I already successfully followed the steps to instal gtk+ at http://www.gtk.org/

when I run the Makefile.pl from Gtk-Perl-0.7000 it gives me:

```
gtkvertmp.c:3:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
Unable to find  Gtk version...
Invoking gendefs.pl with [].
Please wait, this may take a moment...
gtktypexp.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtktypeutils.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtktypeutils.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I have:

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
:/Users/one/gtk/source/gtk+-2.24.16/gtk:/Users/one/gtk/inst/include/gtk-2.0/gtk:/Users/one/gtk/inst/lib/pkgconfig
```

I do have the gtk.h file in my system. I've searched online but haven't gotten Gtk-Perl to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac OS need [libgtk](http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php) to be installed to run the script properly.

Comment: I did go to that website https://live.gnome.org/GTK%2B/OSX/Building and follow the steps upto "jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-core" that was the last command I successfully ran. How can I get libgtk?